# How can lighttpd or php load a different website for the client and output that?

Tags: php, linux, web, webserver, lighttpd

I need a reliable way to retrieve a complete page from a website serverside including css, js and images and show it to clients correctly.

I am able to show the pure html using php's `file_get_contents("http://different-website/desired_page")`, but I need all resources to show it correctly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to rewrite all the URLs on the returned page to point to a proxy page on your server, for example you would need to turn the URL `/site/script.js` in to `/proxy.php?page=http://different-website/site/script.js`.

This is easier said than done however, so I would just use one of the many pre-build PHP proxy scripts.